# Implementing a dice game

Tags: python

Katarina is developing a two-player dice game.
The players roll two 6-sided dice each and get points depending on what they
roll. There are 5 rounds in a game. In each round, each player rolls the two dice.

The rules are:

• The points rolled on each player’s dice are added to their score.
• If the total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to their score.

• If the total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracted from their score.

• If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled added to
their score.

• The score of a player cannot go below 0 at any point.

• The person with the highest score at the end of the 5 rounds wins.

• If both players have the same score at the end of the 5 rounds, they each roll 1 die and
whoever gets the highest score wins (this repeats until someone wins).
Only authorised players are allowed to play the game.
Where appropriate, input from the user should be validated.

Design, develop, test and evaluate a program that:

1. Allows two players to enter their details, which are then authenticated to ensure that they are
   authorised players.
2. Allows each player to roll two 6-sided dice.
3. Calculates and outputs the points for each ro
   und and each player’s total score.
4. Allows the players to play 5 rounds.
5. If both players have the same score after 5 rounds, allows each player to roll 1 die each until
   someone wins.
6. Outputs who has won at the end of the 5 rounds.
7. Stores the winner’s score, and their name, in an external file.
8. Displays the score and player name of the top 5 winning scores from the external file

This is all that I was able to do I don't know how to do the rest of the instrcutions I needed to do. Thank You and help is appreciated.

```py
name = input("Enter Your Name")
if name == "Name":
    pwd= input ("Enter Password")
    if pwd == 'password':
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Incorrect login, checkdetails and try again")

else:
    print("Incorrect Username")


min = 1
max = 6
score =  0
roll = "yes"
answer = "no"

import time
import random

roll = input("Roll the dice?")
while roll == "yes" or roll =="y":
     print("Rolling...")
     dice1 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print(dice1)
     time.sleep(1)

     dice2 = (random.randint(min,max))
     print (dice2)
     time.sleep(1)

     total1 = dice1 + dice2
     score = (score + total1)
     if total1 == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11:
         score = (score +5)
     else:
          total1 == 2 or 4 or 6 or  8 or 10 or 12
          score = (score +10)
     roll == ("Your total score is", score)
```

What I expect is for the dice to roll twice giving me two numbers and show the score which doesn't work the dice keeps rolling.

Comment: Your question should be well-defined and be focused on a single problem. What requirements are you not satisfying? Break it up and work on **one** at a time instead of posting your entire program. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
A general "I don't know what to do next" suggests a tutorial for general learning, or a tutor for focused help.  This site doesn't do those.

Answer (score 1):

Place `roll = input("Roll the dice?")` also at the end of your while loop and add the `print` to get score:

```
while roll == "yes" or roll =="y":
     print("Rolling...")
     ...
     print("Your total score is", score)
     roll = input("Roll the dice?")
```